# setState callback is executing before render finish in react 16

Tags: reactjs, react-16

I have piece of code,

```
this.setState({ generateGraphTableforPDF: true }, () => {
 this.generatePDFData(true);
 this.setState({ generateGraphTableforPDF: false });
});
```

This setstate callback executes before render finish so, in dom there is no table hence empty pdf is generated.

I tried to remove the callback function and wrote them in componentDidUpdate with settimeout 0. But the issue is this is also failing in some scenarios.

Comment: Also post your `generatePDFData` function.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the logic inside your callback-function does not run synchronously. `this.generatePDFData(true)` does not complete before executing `this.setState({ generateGraphTableforPDF: false })`

Your flow of logic should look something like this instead so all procedures are finished before executing the next step:

```
handleChangeOrWhateverFunction = () => {
    this.setState({
       generateGraphTableforPDF: true
    })
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
   if(this.state.generateGraphTableforPDF && prevState.generateGraphTableforPDF !== this.state.generateGraphTableforPDF){
       this.generatePDFData(true)
   }
}

generatePDFData = (boolean) => {
...pdf generating logic
   this.setState({
      generateGraphTableforPDF: false
   })
}
```

Comment: Didnot work cz  the table is created in render (using child component) after setState  and its taking longer time and till then parent's componentDidUpdate is called.

render () {
{this.state.generateGraphTableforPDF ? (
                    <TableContainer tableData={tableData}
                            startIndex={tableData.startIndex}
                            lastIndex={tableData.lastIndex}
                            getDataFromParent={tableData.getDataFromParent}
                            forPdf
                        /> ) : null}}
However same code worked fine in react15

Answer (score 0):

You can do this,

```
this.setState({ generateGraphTableforPDF: true }, () => {
   this.generatePDFData(true);
});

function generatePDFData(bool){
   //Your logic to generate PDF
   this.setState({ generateGraphTableforPDF: false });
}
```